# Add fields to expanded AWS CloudWatch log insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

For my logs I parse the `@message` field to extract relevant data and display that in the log insights, however if you expand a row you get a list of fields & values which only shows the default ones of: `@ingestionTime, @log, @logStream, @message & @timestamp`.

Is there any way to add these custom fields parsed from the `@message` into this list?

[image]